# Can't access phpMyAdmin - I am getting redirected to a vhost

Tags: web-server, virtualhost, apache2, opensuse

My phpMyAdmin is located at `/srv/www/htdocs/phpMyAdmin/`.
The IP of the webserver is *192.168.40.40*

If I try to access phpMyAdmin like this: `http://192.168.40.40/phpMyAdmin` then I get redirected to a vhost which I created for a project (entwicklung.company).

VHOST of a project which I am getting redirected to, if I call `entwicklung.phpmyadmin`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName entwicklung.company
    ServerAdmin black@company.de
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/vhosts/company
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/company_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/company_access.log common

    <Directory "/srv/www/vhosts/company">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

So I tried to create a virtual host for phpMyAdmin, but then I get `403 permission denied` if I try to call it.

User and group are set to `wwwrun` with `chown -R wwwrun:wwwrun /srv/www/vhosts/phpMyAdmin`

VHOST for phpMyAdmin:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName entwicklung.phpmyadmin
    ServerAdmin black@company.de
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/vhosts/phpMyAdmin
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/phpmyadmin_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/phpmyadmin_access.log common

    <Directory "/srv/www/vhosts/phpMyAdmin">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: What's in the error log? And what is in the other vhost?

Comment: There is nothing related to the redirection, in the error log. Which other vhost do you mean? And what exactly do you mean with "whats is in the other vhost?"

Comment: You're getting a redirection, but it's from a URL that doesn't correspond to the vhost you posted above. So you need to look at the configuration of the other vhost.

Comment: I get redirected to the VHOST which I have posted above.

Comment: Exactly! So that vhost configuration doesn't matter. It's the one you were redirected FROM that will contain the redirect.

Comment: I updated my post. I actually get 403 access denied, if I create the vhost for phpmyadmin and try to access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it, I had to change the owner of /srv/www/vhosts/phpMyAdmin to wwwrun:root with

`chown -R wwwrun:root /srv/www/vhosts/phpMyAdmin`